# What environment to use in writing formal deductions?

Tags: lists, arrays, logic

Learning about mathematical logic, I have to write formal deductions*.

How can I write them using TeX?

Any feedback is welcome.

---

(*)Roughly they are numbered lists over two columns, the first one gives a formula and the second one gives its justification (if it is an axiom, a hypothesis or if it is inferred by previous entries), both can go over many rows.
Anyway here is an example (from: Mendelson, Intro. to Math. Logic.)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a tabular environment using a a `p{}` column type, and a custom counter for the first column?

Comment: the notation you're using is very like that used in the article "[ProofCheck: Writing and checking complete proofs in LaTeX](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95neveln.pdf)" by Bob Neveln and Bob Alps. this was presented at tug 2009, and a [video](http://river-valley.tv/writing-and-checking-complete-proofs-in-latex/) is available.  you might get some ideas from this.  the authors presented an update at tug 2012, but unfortunately, this year's meeting wasn't recorded; the tugboat article will be published in the proceedings issue (but hasn't yet been received).

Comment: Have a look at http://http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/ . There is a list of solutions for writing logical proofs in LaTeX

Comment: As @Guido's link seems broken (missing column?), I repost it here http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using a custom counter for the first column, and the `p{}` column types for the other two columns:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcounter{MyRowNumber}
\newcommand*{\NewRow}{\stepcounter{MyRowNumber}\arabic{MyRowNumber}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l p{0.25\linewidth} p{0.25\linewidth}}
    \NewRow & $x^2 + y^2 \ge 0\ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ & Hyp\\
    \NewRow & $more\ math$                                   & 10,11 conjunction introduction\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```